# Javascript - Avoiding variable redundancy in nested for loops

Tags: javascript

**Please bear with me, I could only explain the problem in the comments of the code snippet below. Please read through them carefully. Question at the end:**

I usually tend to name the variables used in `for` loops with `i`, like this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      // do some COMPLEX operations here
 }
```

This looks fairly simple; but when I'm at it I may require nested for loops within the above `for` loop. So, introducing the complexity now:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      // do some
      // VERY
      // COMPLEX
      // operations
      // here

      for (var i = 0; i < javascript_object.list.length; i++) {
          // I may have inadvertently forgot of the variable 'i' was been used earlier
          for (var j = 0; j < javascript_object.list[i].another_list.length; j++) {
              // Perform more complex operations here
          }
      }

      this.getReports(arr[i]) // the value of this i
         // which I now think refer to the first for loop might have been changed
         // in second for loop and may lead to dangerous results! 
 }
```

How to avoid this from happening? How could the variables be named carefully so that it wouldn't clash with other variables being declared elsewhere?

Comment: The only way to prevent any problems is to name them differently. That's not so hard is it?

Comment: Extract complicated logic to functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are we supposed to use short functions to sectionalize our code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/210372/why-are-we-supposed-to-use-short-functions-to-sectionalize-our-code) See also: [Should I extract specific functionality into a function and why?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/166884/should-i-extract-specific-functionality-into-a-function-and-why)

Comment: @Pinocchio Its not too hard when you have nice looking code and very little documentation in place, or may be you introduce all the `for` loops at once. But when there is REALLY complex code that we've to write its hard to spot the `i` within that 'spaghetti' code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One common approach, which is also used in the code you posted is to simply to use the next letter in the alphabet, so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < length; k++) {
            // More loops?
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is lazy, but it works.  However, I find that it can get confusing when you're not looping the same array or accessing a multi-dimensional array.  In that case, a better approach might be to simply provide more meaningful names:

```
for(var nameIndex = 0; nameIndex < names.length; nameIndex++) {
    for(var classroomIndex = 0; classroomIndex < classrooms.length; classroomIndex++) {
        // And so forth
    }
}
```

Of course this may be a little wordy for you, but I figure better a little wordy than completely uncomprehensible code.  You were probably hoping for a neat hack here to be able to keep the `i` variable in its own scope.  There may even exist a way to do so, however I don't believe in that kind of solution to a problem like this for two reasons:

- Nested loops should generally be discouraged anyway.  You cannot apply a best practice in a situation in which you're not following a best practice.  Call a method instead.
- It would leave the next programmer scratching his head wondering why you did it that way, and it is difficult to justify such a decrease in readability just to account for name clashing.

I hope that helps!

Comment: "Nested loops should generally be discouraged anyway" - so generally you would not iterate through a 2d or 3d array with a nested loop? Sometimes it makes sense to extract code into a method, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Hence the "generally" in "Nested loops should generally be discouraged anyway."

Comment: I suppose choosing some meaningful names for the variables makes a lot of sense irrespective of where I use it. Learnt it the hard way though :)

Comment: @Vineeth General rule of thumb though:  If you're having to deal with name clashes in loop variables, good indication to start dividing that function into bite-sized pieces.  :)

Answer (score 14):

Simple:

```
  // This block with a
  // VERY
  // COMPLEX
  // operation
  // here
  // is far too large.
```

When blocks become so large that you cannot see all of your local variable definitions any more, they are definitely too large. Refactor such a parts to a function, this will help a lot to avoid accidentally double declarations.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the value of `i` will definitely be using the one that is in the second for-loop. This is because **variables are function scoped** in JavaScript. So it doesn't matter how many times you `var` it in a function, it will be the same variable.

To avoid this, either give the variables new names or enclose them in other function calls. Since you haven't specified what these "complex" operations are, I can't suggest any good refactoring method other than extracting the second for loop into it's own function.

Comment: I cannot post the entire code here since I will have to adhere to my company's security policies. Refactoring is something I will have to take care but I hadn't done it when I thought of this question in my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Use JSLint or JSHint to lint your code directly inside your IDE / Editor. From the Book ["JavaScript: the Good Parts"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) by [Douglas Crockford](https://github.com/douglascrockford) (author of [JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint)):

> JSLint is a code quality tool for JavaScript. It takes a source text
>   and scans it. If it finds a problem, it returns a message describing
>   the problem and an approximate location within the source. The problem
>   is not necessarily a syntax error, although it often is. JSLint looks
>   at some style conventions as well as structural problems. It does not
>   prove that your program is correct. It just provides another set of
>   eyes to help spot problems.

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"don't use JSLint nor JSHint, don't lint your code directly inside your IDE / Editor."_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to fit [answer] guidelines.

Comment: @gnat Thought it was self explanatory. Well, here you go - an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a transpiler and used the keyword "let" instead of "var", you would get an error at the second declaration.

```
for (let i = 0; i < condition1; ++i) {

    // SyntaxError: Identifier 'i' has already been declared
    for (let i = 0; i < condition2; ++i) {  
    }
}
```

but as others pointed out, https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FunctionLength.html, a function length more than 8 to 10 lines is probably too long.

Comment: You don't need a transpiler if you are using ECMAScript® 2015 ref: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations